# Add setup to GPG symmetric

Tags: encryption, symmetric, pgp, decryption

I use GPG symmetric, to encrypt text file.

Is it possible to use GPG symmetric, to encrypt a text file, and at the same time, add additional setting to the encrypted file, to give us 2 conditions:

- correct password will decrypt it.
- incorrect password will give fake decryption result, instead of indicator "decryption failed, bad session key"

Comment: It's not possible with GPG, and questions about a particular program are not [on-topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). What you are looking at would be a so-called _deniable encryption_ that gives a fake "decryption result". I suggest adjusting the question to de-emphasize GPG, and state your goals more precisely. The hard thing is making the "fake decryption result" credible.

Comment: @fgrieu thank you for the term, I am going to create new question, but do you have the answer ?

Comment: It's best to edit the current question. Again what's asked just can't be done with GPG or OpenPGP. Some forms of deniable encryption exist (e.g. [Veracrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Plausible%20Deniability.html)) but it does not seem to be exactly what you are looking for. I know no silver bullet that would automatically give a plausible fake decryption result, much less a system common enough that using it would not raise suspicion.

Comment: @fgrieu thank you